# How to test form validation in Angular

Tags: validation, angularjs, testing, jasmine, end-to-end

I'm attempting to write tests around a form that uses Angular.

After following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980251/angularjs-accessing-scope-in-e2e-test), I'm able to access the form's scope inside the e2e test. Now with this code:

```
scope('Form', function(scope) {
    scope.email = "test@test.com";
    scope.password = "abcd1234";

    expect(scope.form.$valid).toBe(true);
})
```

For whatever reason, `scope.form.$valid` is false. If I wrap that inside a `setTimeout()`, it works perfectly well. Angular's `sleep()` method is of no use.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

You should `$digest` the scope adding `scope.$digest()` after the last scope.password.

Comment: Apologies, there were a few more steps necessary to get this working, but you are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mimo's advice, I arrived at a final solution.

A custom dsl statement had to be constructed, in order to fool `expect` into taking a Future.

```
angular.scenario.dsl('expectScope', function() {
  var _retrieve = function(source, target) {
      if(target == '') return source;
      var targets = target.split('.');
      var nextTarget = targets[0];
      return _retrieve(source[nextTarget], targets.splice(1).join('.') );
  };
  var chain = angular.extend({}, angular.scenario.matcher);

  chain.not = function() {
      this.inverse = true;
      return chain;
  };

  return function(scope, name) {
      this.future = new angular.scenario.Future('scope.'+name, function() {});
      this.future.value = _retrieve(scope, name);
      return chain;
  };
});
```

By calling `scope.$digest` before `expectScope(scope, 'value.othervalue')`, everything now works as expected.