# Get DOM element by scope $id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I understand I can get the scope by element:

```
scope = angular.element($0).scope();
scope.$id; // "003"
```

How do I get reverse: Find the DOM element using the scope `$id`, such as `003`?

I'd like to do this for debugging purposes. My scope tree shows something and I'd like to identify where it came from.

Comment: you can get the scope by getting the id of the element, <div id="abc"></div>

Comment: i dont know if you can do what you are trying to achieve, have you tried batarang?

Comment: I've definitely tried batarang, that's why I know the mysterious scope id. I want to find what element it might be attached to. I'm asking for the opposite of what's being suggested.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Although it's not very sexy each dom node gets a class ng-scope so you could tech do something like this maybe:

```
function getScope(id) {
var elem;
$('.ng-scope').each(function(){
    var s = angular.element(this).scope(),
        sid = s.$id;

    if(sid == id) {
        elem = this;
        return false; // stop looking at the rest
    }
});
return elem;
}
```

Comment: Does the trick. Guess I thought there'd be a list of scopes somewhere ripe for the fetching :)

Comment: I'm with ya. I wish there was too as I've encountered a need for this very thing.

Comment: If it's a real use case, don't forget you can also crawl up from $rootScope. I've used DOM vs rootScope traversal to count and always get different numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21776522/111243

Comment: seems like directives don't necessarily have `.ng-scope` -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/26413528/1037948

Comment: I think most people want this for when they aren't using a directive...you wouldn't need this unless you are doing something pretty advanced.

Comment: @user2173353 What do you mean the `$element` on the controller? Then pass it into the directive?

Comment: This is only true in development mode. You should not use this as it does not work in release mode.

Answer (score 7):

Trying out the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23255103/1037948), I found that directives don't seem to have the class `ng-scope`, so here's a modified version that'll fallback to everything.

```
var getByScopeId = function(id) { 
    var filterfn = function(i,el) {
        var sc = angular.element(el).scope();

        return sc && sc.$id == id;
    };
    // low hanging fruit -- actual scope containers
    var result = $('.ng-scope').filter(filterfn);
    if(result && result.length) return result;

    // try again on everything...ugh
    return $(':not(.ng-scope)').filter(filterfn);
}
```

Usage:

```
var results = getByScopeId('003')
```

Comment: note: should use something more optimized than the `.filter` fn, i.e. stop after success http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/3vLwzgkh/3/

Comment: Note: scope() only works when debug data is enabled. This is usually turned off in production for performance

Comment: It did technically work for me but I don't understand the results:
n.fn.init
  context: document
  length: 0
  prevObject: n.fn.init(2304) [...]
  [[Prototype]]: Object(0)

Comment: Ah, I see. Despite being present in the page when I output {{$id}} the function didn't find the ID I was looking for (hence `length:0`)

Answer (score 5):

The same solution written in es2015, without JQuery dependency:

```
getElementFromScopeId = (id) => [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.ng-scope')).map((x) => angular.element(x)).filter(x => x.scope().$id == id).pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version that detects and handles isolate scopes correctly and stops as soon as it finds the element. Angular's `.scope()` and `.isolateScope()` functions use the jquery `.data()` object and if a scope is not found, they search up through the parent nodes of the element. We're already searching through all nodes, so it's a lot more efficient to skip the parent search and inspect `.data()` directly.

```
const findScopeElement = $scope => {
    const {$id, $root} = $scope;
    let result;
    const isolate = $scope !== $root &&
        Object.getPrototypeOf($scope) === Object.getPrototypeOf($root);
    const cls = isolate ? '.ng-isolate-scope' : '.ng-scope';
    const search = (i, e) => {
        const data = $(e).data();
        const scope = isolate ? data.$isolateScope : data.$scope;
        if(scope && scope.$id === $id) {
            result = e;
            return false;
        }
    };
    $(cls).each(search);
    if(!result) {
        // could be an attribute directive
        $(`:not(${cls})`).each(search);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always get the scope using element's **id**.

**Example:**

html:

```
<div id="myId"></div>
```

js:

```
  var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#myId'));
  var myScope = angular.element(myEl).scope();
```

Live example : http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/7XQA7/2/

also as David Chase suggested, you can always use [batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) - Extends Chrome Developer Tools, adding tools for debugging and profiling AngularJS applications.

Comment: It's the other way around. I have the **scope** id and want the element.