# $scope object taking previously created $scope object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am stuck in one situation plz help.
I have used jqxTree in my app, when I click on context menu and open a jqxwindow, new `$scope` is getting Created, and it is showing previously created `$scope` object.

```
$get.h.$new.a {
  $id: "7P3",
  this: $get.h.$new.a,
  $$listeners: Object,
  $$listenerCount: Object,
  $parent: $get.h.$new.a…
}
```

This Scope is getting Created when Controller is getting called.
And when I get an element using scope ID, it is not showing that Div element upon which it is creating new scope. I have used this code to get Element using scope Id.
[Get DOM element by scope $id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253506/get-dom-element-by-scope-id)

```
$get.h.$new.a {
  $id: "3ZJ",
  this: $get.h.$new.a
  $$listeners: Object
  $$listenerCount: Object,
  $parent: null…
}
```

And this Scope is getting Created without calling controller.