# Angular get scope by scope.$id

Tags: angularjs

I want to know, how to get scope by scope.**$id**. I know that I can get all scopes in page and then I can find that one scope, but I looking for simpler implementation.

For instance: 
 
1. I want to get scope which id is **100** from **$rootScope**:

```
$rootScope.$getScope(100)
```

2. From current **$scope** or variable **angular**

```
$scope.$getScope(100)
angular.scope(100)
```

Can I get specified scope in that way?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253506/get-dom-element-by-scope-id/23255103#23255103

Comment: Thanks, I know that it works, but I want to avoid DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

Answer form comments is using jQuery. If you want plain javascript, more functional approach, you could do:

```
function getScope(scopeId){
     return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".ng-scope"))
     .map(el => angular.element(el).scope())
     .filter(scope => scope.$id == scopeId)[0]
}

$rootScope.getScope = getScope;
```

As far as I know there is no  other way to find all scopes on page than just query for `.ng-scope`.

Comment: Hmm.. okej, but It also based on DOM elements, it's similar to first solution @SaEChowdary (link is below question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253506/get-dom-element-by-scope-id/23255103#23255103)), but I'm looking for solution without using DOM elements.